On principal ideals and GCD
I am currently studying algebraic number theory and came across the following exercise:
Let $A$ and $B$ be two ideals in the ring of integers $R$ of some number field. Then there exists some $\alpha\in A$ such that $\gcd([\alpha],AB)=A$.
I attempted prove this statement by performing induction on the number of distinct prime ideal factorss of $B$:
Suppose $B=P^m$ for some prime ideal $P$. If for every $\alpha$, $\gcd([\alpha],AB)\ne A$, then we have $A\cdot P|[\alpha]$. This implies $A\subset A\cdot P$, so $A=AP$, which contradicts the unique factorization of ideals in $R$.
Assume now $B$ has more than one distinct prime ideal factors. Write $B=P^mB'$ for some prime ideal $P$ and some $B'$ coprime to $P$. By inductive hypothesis, we can choose $\alpha_1\in A$ such that $\gcd([\alpha_1],AB')=A$ and $\alpha_2\in AB'$ such that $\gcd([\alpha_2],AB)=AB'$. This means
$$
A=\gcd([\alpha_1],\gcd([\alpha_2],AB))=\gcd([\alpha_1,\alpha_2],AB),
$$
but I don't know how to proceed further.

See Proposition $20.13$ in this question. $\ \ $

Write $A=P_1^{a_1}P_2^{a_2}\cdots P_k^{a_k}$ and $AB=P_1^{b_1}P_2^{b_2}\cdots P_k^{b_k}Q_1^{c_1}Q_2^{c_2}\cdots Q_l^{c_l}$ for distinct prime ideals $P_1,P_2,\dots,P_k,Q_1,Q_2,\dots,Q_l$ and positive integers $a_1,\dots,a_k,b_1,\dots,b_k,c_1,\dots,c_l$ such that $b_i\ge a_i$ for all $1\le i\le k$.
Choose $\alpha_i\in P_i^{a_i}-P_i^{a_i+1}$, so by the Chinese remainder theorem, we can find $\alpha\in R$ such that
$$
\alpha\equiv\alpha_i\pmod{P_i^{a_i}},\quad \alpha\equiv1\pmod{Q_j},
$$
for all $1\le i\le k$ and $1\le j\le l$, so we have $\gcd([\alpha],AB)=A$.
